# Deleting record using laravel and vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I'm stuck in making a delete method using vue js and laravel. I tried to add a value to the `href` attribute using laravel resource and pass an `id` as a second parameter but when I click on it and display the id on console it shows the same id to all data which is incorrect.

Sample blade:

```
<a id="deleteRecord" data-id="{{$project->id}}" @click.prevent="deleteRecord" class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-danger" href="{{ route('projects.store', $project->id) }}">
   <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Vue method:

```
deleteRecord: function(id) {
  var dataId = $('#deleteRecord').attr('href')
  console.log(dataId);
}
```

Comment: Laravel resource only deletes with `DELETE` method. You have to use `axios` and send a `DELETE` query.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, yeah but I know this can be done using vue and display some cool confirmation modals or something like that.

Comment: Of course. `axios` lives inside of your `Vue` method. Ok, it doesn't have to be axios. Any http client can do.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your method deleteRecord:

```
this.$http.delete(url)
.success(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}) 
.error(function(errors) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Or using axios inside of your method

```
axios.delete(url)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: You have to manually add axios with `npm install --save axios` and require it in your Vuejs. `axios` is a JS library.

Comment: Did you try the first method? `this.$http.delete(url, {'method': 'DELETE' });`

Comment: yeah without `axios` but says `Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined`

Comment: Ok. Have a look here. He does exactly what I am saying using `this.$http.delete()` http://felicianoprochera.com/simple-task-app-with-laravel-5-3-and-vuejs/. Just scroll down the page, you will see how it uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. I'll just post it here to help others also.

```
deleteRecord: function(id) {
  var url = "projects" + "/" + id;
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
      success: function(response) {
          //do some success stuff here..
      }
  });
}
```